# Entity Framework Stored Proc error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to read in a stored procedure from Entity Framework but it is telling me that the execute function is unknown. Any ideas on how to fix it or call in my stored procedure?

```
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         using (Brand_SASEntities1 context = new Brand_SASEntities1())
         { 
             Console.WriteLine("Calling the SP to read data in")
             int records = context.ExecuteFunction("GetOptInData"); 
             Console.WriteLine ("{0} records are found", records); 
             Console.ReadKey(); 
             Console.ReadKey(); 
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: have you added it an a *Function Import*?

Comment: Also: what approach (code-first vs. database-first) are you using? Do you have an `.edmx` visual model of your database? And which **version** of .NET / Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: I am using Code first and 2013 . Net with 5.0 entity framwork, and yes I do have a visual model as well.

Comment: Yes I have added the SP as a function import in the EF